# SQL query: confusing query

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
     Flights(flight_num, source_city, dest_city)
     Departures(flight_num, date, plane_type)
     Passengers(passenger_id, passenger_name, passenger_address)
     Bookings(passenger_id, flight_num, date, seat_number)
```

And I want to find the number of departures for each type of plane for all flights that leave from Burbank. (Make sure the plane¬¬_type is also part of the result.)

So far I have

```
     SELECT D.plane_type, COUNT(*)
     FROM Departures D, Flights F
     WHERE F.source_city = “Burbank”
     AND F.flight_num = D.flight_num
     GROUP BY D.plane_type
```

But I am not sure how to incorporate the fact that the planes might change for the same flight number?

Comment: Does your current query not work? What is wrong with its output? It appears your query should work - it should produce one count for each plane type for each flight.

Comment: Should it be COUNT(B.flight_num)

Comment: Can you please create an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with sample data that demonstrates your problem with the current query, and post the link in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve that behaviour if yours plane_type changes with no rules.